# Search questions asked by me and with the D3.js tag

Tags: support, search

I would like to search questions asked by me and with [tag D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js). How can I do that?

Comment: [`user:1914781 is:q [d3.js]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1914781+is%3Aq+%5Bd3.js%5D&searchOn=1)

Comment: Thanks, how to get the user ID? and I would like to sort by date as well.

Comment: It's easier to use `user:mine` for yourself.

Comment: [How to find my UserID in Stack Overflow](/q/281254/15497888) and sorting by date is the same as anywhere else. Just [hit "Newest"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRm6a.png)

Comment: Fotoyour profile on stackoverflow and you see in the search bar ,our I'd only the number there you can search by addind search terms . Also when you click on tags in your profile and select one you get all your answers and questions to that tag